# Защита от диалога с сервером сторонней программой

Tags: клиент-сервер

Есть клиентское приложение и сервер, которые должны между собой общаться.
Как реализовать их соединение (со случайным хешом), чтобы никто не мог  эмулировать работу приложения через HTTP?

Comment: Что это за mobile такой? какая платформа?

Comment: Маловероятно, что ТС сам понимает что пишет.

Comment: Автор хочет,  чтобы нельзя было, создать левое приложение, которое подключается к серверу и выдает себя за оригинальную программу.

Comment: https, не?

Comment: Интересует решение помимо https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**https** **SSL** все уже давно написано, тут идет шифрование, а передавать данные можно с солью, если конечно есть необходимость такая. Врядли ТС разрабатывает ПО для пентагона или нашего ФСБ, чат или что-то подобное.
Просто все всегда, в самом начале хотят защитить все что только можно. Не НУЖНО ТАК ДЕЛАТЬ! бессмысленная трата времени и сил.

Шифруй и прячь только нужное, проверяй все что можно, но не усложняй проект непонятными вещами!

Comment: Спасибо, о ССЛ как-то забыл. Но хочется с самого начала делать все правильно.

Comment: нужно, правильно и хочется иногда ходят ой как не рядом!

Answer (score 2):

Принципиально — никак.

Вы даете исполнимый код клиенту. Клиент может проанализировать этот код и создать свой, выполняющий те же функции. Можно только затруднить этот процесс, обфусцировав код и затруднив его анализ.

Все HTTPS и прочие варианты SSL, подписи любыми алгоритмами и прочее это, собственно, и делают. Но никто не запретит клиенту вытащить из приложения ключ (сертификат SSL, параметры HMAC или что-либо еще) и сделать такой же запрос. Вся защита строится только на том, что большинству или не будет необходимости или не хватит квалификации или будет банально лень этим заниматься.

Точнее, есть один вариант. Если платформа и ОС поддерживает TPM с trusted path начиная с UEFI secure boot, то можно выкрутиться, выполняя подписи через TPM-чип, когда доступ к ключу подписывания будет только у доверенного кода. Но таких систем на рынке почти нет и, предположительно, не будет (это на новых устройствах типа планшетов такое пройдет, а на десктопных PC из-за неприспособленности экосистемы непривычные потребители взвоют белугой и банально бойкотируют продукт кошельками).

Comment: Вот и я о том же.

Answer (score 1):

Реальный пример из флэш-игр, общающихся  с сервером по HTTP (для размышления):

1. Для пакета данных, отправляемого клиентом, вычисляется подпись.
2. Подпись кладется в HTTP-заголовок.
3. Сервер перед обработкой пакета (выполнением команды) проверяет подпись.

Comment: А можно более подробно о подписи?

Comment: Обычное шифрование с открытым ключом в режиме подписи.

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать свой протокол (не уровня транспорта - транспорт ясное дело HTTP, а уровня приложения) с тем, чтобы клиент и сервер общались собственным проприетарным протоколом?

Ну скажем все данные паковать в XML/JSon с передачей хэша пакета? Сервер получает, распаковывает пакет, парсит, проверяет хэш далее выдача.

Comment: Как я понимаю, нужно иметь секретный ключ, который захардкоджений в приложении, при декомпиляции его можно добыть и тогда смысл такой защиты теряется.

Comment: @chandler, разумеется. Большинство защит в любом случае могут быть взломаны. Важно соотношение стоимости усилий вложенных в защиту к профиту который получит взломщик или "упущенной выгоде", которую потерпит владелец ПО. Поэтому соглашусь со @Shrek. Защищайте на том уровне, на каком это имеет смысл и не более. 

В том же игровом мире, как ни изощряются разработчики, ботов к играм все равно клепают и будут клепать.